# Is there a way to set up @Before and @After on cucumber test projects?

Tags: cucumber

I have this code set up on a Hooks.java class

```
@Before("@Tag")
    public static void before() {
        System.out.println("Hooks inicando o driver");
        driver = DriverTypeFactory.getDriver(DriverTypeFactory.GECKO_DRIVER);
    }
    public static WebDriver getDriver(){
        return driver;
    }
    @After
    public static void after() {
        System.out.println("Hooks encerrando o driver");
        driver.close();
    }
```

All the webdriver stuff works correctly, however i wanted to open and close the browser everytime a test ends.

However the Before and After steps won't execute no matter what i try. even those prints i set up wont appear on the console, so im sure the Cucumber code just skips the Before and jumps directly to my @Given Step.
Anyone knows some solution?

Comment: What do your imports look like? And did you put the hooks in the same package as the step definitions? How are you even running Cucumber?

Comment: Cucumber and JUnit both have the same annontations for Before and After. It is possible that you have made an import mistake.

Share your imports as proposed above by @M.P. Korstanje

Comment: package test.pepino.hooks;

import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import test.core.web.enums.DriverTypeFactory;

Those are my imports, sorry i dindn't mention the steps definitions cause i've set up those correctly, if i call some 'createDrive' method on one of the step definitions the test works properly, the problem seems to be on the setup of my hooks